# failed applying security patch SUPEE-11155 - Hunk #1 FAILED

Tags: magento-1.9, security

```
patching file app/Mage.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 813.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/Mage.php.rej
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why I've a bunch of messages that say `Hunk #1 FAILED`
I run `PHP 7.2` with `Magento 1.9.3.1` and I'm applying the correct patch.

Comment: You may have missed `SUPEE-11086`. Check in your `app/etc/applied.patches.list`.

Answer (score 0):

"Hunk failed" error message indicates that your *app/Mage.php* is modified (especially around line 813) and patch tool cannot find a place to add/remove patching code lines.

It is required to review your *app/Mage.php* comparing it with original file from 1.9.3.1 distribution to understand nature of this difference.

*app/Mage.php* file for 1.9.3.1 version was updated in **SUPEE-10415**, **SUPEE-10570v2**, **SUPEE-11086** patches and it is required to have all these patches installed prior to **SUPEE-11155**. So as the first step, please make sure you have all these patches installed.

If these changes in *app/Mage.php* are some custom code approved by you or your developer, you may need to apply the failed hunk manually, you can find it in [unified diff format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Unified-Format.html) right in the patch file (*PATCH_SUPEE-11155_CE_1.9.3.1_v3-2019-06-18-08-15-43.sh*):

```
diff --git app/Mage.php app/Mage.php
index a0aa92a440d..02147d3ad43 100644
--- app/Mage.php
+++ app/Mage.php
@@ -813,9 +813,9 @@ final class Mage
             ',',
             (string) self::getConfig()->getNode('dev/log/allowedFileExtensions', Mage_Core_Model_Store::DEFAULT_CODE)
         );
-        $logValidator = new Zend_Validate_File_Extension($_allowedFileExtensions);
         $logDir = self::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'log';
-        if (!$logValidator->isValid($logDir . DS . $file)) {
+        $validatedFileExtension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
+        if (!$validatedFileExtension || !in_array($validatedFileExtension, $_allowedFileExtensions)) {
             return;
         }
```

Otherwise, you may need to revert *app/Mage.php* to original version from 1.9.3.1 and re-apply all previous patches to that file (**SUPEE-10415**, **SUPEE-10570v2**, **SUPEE-11086**).